# Upgrade problem - "dependency problems prevent configuration of libnih-dbus1"

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade, release-upgrade

I have a problem with the upgrading....

When i write 
`sudo dpkg --configure -a` , this is what happens... :

```
dependency problems prevent configuration of libnih-dbus1:
 libnih-dbus1 depends on libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu9); however:
  Version of libnih1 on system is 1.0.3-4ubuntu2.
 libnih-dbus1 depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.4); however:
  Package libc6 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libnih-dbus1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libnih-dbus1
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, hence finding this post. I had started an upgrade then my pc had been turned off.

Fixed it with

```
apt-get -f install
```

Seemed that `libc6` wanted to ask if it was OK to stop services to continue - I was upgrading headless using screen. The upgrade didn't get an answer to that question thus `libc6` wasn't installed.

Carrying on the `do-release-upgrade` now.